Powershell script for polices in win 8.1
I have a problem with "few" computers with windows 8.1.
I have about 150 PC's not connected to any network (they cannot be connected to any network whatsoever) and in my work they change password polices and other stuff. I don't want to manually enter "gpedit" one by one so I'm looking quick solution.
How can I block password manager in I.E. (I must use I.E. due to polices restriction).

You can use reg add commands to set registry settings. Check these posts, seem related or to get you closer: https://admx.help/?Category=InternetExplorer&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.InternetExplorer::RestrictFormSuggest, https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/agalz7/internet_explorer_autocomplete_forms_disabled_in/?rdt=51207, and https://community.spiceworks.com/t/internet-explorer-gpo-to-disable-password-saving-for-specific-site/750341/3 .... figuring out which ones work for your need is trivial but will need to test, then use reg add to run script manually saving a little time.

Yes i know that, but let me explain.

Ok, please explain—no problem. It sounds like you have machines you have to touch each physically as per "not connected to any network whatsoever". Please do explain if you have any further clarity, if you cannot network connect them, it leaves you with touching each and running so scripting configs can save you time. You will need to find a solution that suffices for one machine manually via trial and error, etc. and once a solution is determined that works for your need, then figure out how to script it out, automate, etc. for those configs. Please clarify further what you mentioned though.

I provided you with 3 links for 3 potential solutions that will need to be tested that seem relevant to your ultimate goal for the password manager settings of the web browser on these machines. These may be good starting points for your test/trial and error to confirm. Once that is confirmed, then whatever you want to set, then it'll be time to figure out how to script those configs out, log into machine, run script from USB drive, etc. You said 'no network whatsoever' and a 'quick solution' with those in mind, that's what I have thus far.

I have about 150 machines that can’t be connected to any network and due to policy changes I need to change almost all aspects through gpedit.msc one by one things like block installation new devices via USB, BitLocker settings etc. I already done some kind of solution with reg file blocking autofilling passwords and users in explorer and Firefox but there is so much more stuff :) So my question is: is there any shorter way to do that via Shell commands for gpedit, can I do all things via win registry and it is enough?

It depends on what solutions and settings in particular work for your needs. It may be a mix of things, Win 8.1 is pretty old so I cannot test that to confirm. You can test though and get one machine with all settings locked down for your needs. You can check "C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicyUsers" and "C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy" folders to see if you copy those over to another machine if it'll work for just the gpedit.msc configs. Check out https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-security-baselines/lgpo-exe-local-group-policy-object-utility-v1-0/ba-p/701045 too.

Thanks for support and solutions. They were very helpful. I've made a reg file with almost all settings. Things like Bitlocker and stuff are still "work in progress" but it shorten my work about 80%. Thx one more time you're best! Cheers.

You're welcome, and here is a super user post I wrote up on TPM settings with I think Windows 7 back then so it should be applicable to Windows 8.1 if any of this helps with anything you are working regarding Bitlocker: https://superuser.com/questions/1104810/clearing-tpm-does-not-ask-for-new-password-but-change-owner-password-asks-for/1115768#1115768. Just in case I wanted to share as there is a section labeled "Configuring Local Group Policy Settings for BitLocker" with some steps, screen shots, etc. Should be possible to PowerShell script some of that but not sure 100% without testing.
